# WSO2 issue with AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am able to install WSO2 API manager and BAM on my AWS ec2 instance. I am able to publish the API through publisher. But when I am trying to access the API through store I am getting this error "WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-*".
Also I like to mention I am able to connect with RDBMS on the time of API call.

Is there anything I am missing on server configuration? What ever port open are required I have open it. Please suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using wrong ports in your requests here. Use 8280 and 8243 for http/https respectively. 9763/9443 are management ports and intended to be used for accessing the management console.

Comment: "ERROR - APIKeyMgtServiceComponent Error in initializing thrift transport
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not bind to port 10397
" this error I am getting on the API manager start.

Comment: make sure that those ports are unblocked on aws. also, you'll get port conflict issues if you run two wso2 products on the same node without configuring a port offset, so configure a port offset if there are multiple servers running there.

Comment: 10397 port is open and when I am calling the API it giving me this error also "SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
"

Comment: this is a certificate issue. if it's a self-signed certificate, you'll need to import the self-signed certificate to the client (browser? then you can accept the certificate after trying the url).

Comment: Is there any way to call the API without SSL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95666/discussion-between-shantanu-karmakar-and-rajeev-sampath).